# how to run mysql container using Apache Mesos/Marathon

Tags: containers, mesos, marathon

I'm trying to use Apache Marathon to run my container based application.
For this I've installed Mesos, Zookeeper, marathon and Docker. Is there anything other than that I need to install.
I'm trying Simple docker-based application in this
https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/application-basics.html

I am not able to run this, it is only showing deploying

maratho giving INFO delaying /basic-3 due to backoff. 
Is the procedure I followed correct. Any help is much appreciated. I've installed my master and slave on same machine

thanks

Comment: Check the Marathon log (in syslog) to see if Marathon is actually receiving offers and trying to launch your task. Check the Mesos master log to see if Mesos sees the task launch request and forwards it to the slave. Check the Mesos slave log to see if container is pulled and started.

Comment: @Adam, I'm getting in mesos `HTTP request for '/master/state.json'`
what does this mean. Do I need to worry about this.

Comment: No need to worry about those lines. That just means that either a) you hit the Mesos webUI yourself, b) the mesos CLI queried the master to find out about running tasks, or c) Marathon queried the master. If you go to http://<master_ip:port>/master/state.json yourself, you'll get out a json blob containing state on the slaves, frameworks and tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you first check whether your cluster is that up correctly?

1. Check whether in the Mesos UI (hostname:5050 by default) whether the slaves are registered
2. Can you run a simple marathon job such as 'sleep 30' to check the marathon configuration?

Joerg

P.S. You could also check whether Mesos is currently pulling the docker (?) image which might take while. Therefore you might want to look into the Mesos log...

Comment: I'm using only one slave and it is registered. I'm able to run the job "sleep 30". I need to run a mysql container and link it with tomcat container. Is this possible to do using marathon.

Comment: So you want to co-locate containers? Unfortunately that is not yet supported, but there is effort into that direction. Considering your initial problem: I would assume that mesos is pulling the docker image (which depending on your network speed might take a while). You could check in the mesos logs....